# Reduce database writes with memached

Tags: mysql, memcached

I would like to convert my stats tracking system not to write to the database directly, as we're hitting bottlenecks.

We're currently using memcached for certain aspects of the site, and I wanted to use it for storing stats and committing them to mysql DB periodically.

The issue lies however in the number of items (which is in the millions) for which potentially there could be stats collected between the cronjob runs that would commit them into the database. Other than running a `SELECT * FROM data` and checking for existence of every single memcache key, and then updating the table.... is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It sounds just like the `insert delayed` fucntionality allready in MySQL? Maybe that's another option.

Comment: Already using it, but still hitting mysql connection limits at peak hours.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm not saying below is gospel, this is just my gut feeling. As said later on, I don't have the specifics of your system :) And obviously no offence meant etc :) )

I would advice against using memcached for this. Memcached is build te quickly retrieve values that you've gotten before, not to store values. The big difference is that is your cache is getting full, you'll loose your data.

Normally, you'd just have no data in your cache, and recollect the data from the source, which is impossible in this case. That alone would be a reason for me to try an dissuade you from this.

Now you say the major problem is the mysql connection limit you are hitting. If you do simple stuff (like what we talked about in the comments: the `insert delayed`), it's just a case of increasing the limit. You should probably have enough power to have your scripts/users go to the database once and say "this should eventually be added", and then go away. If your users can't even open 1 connection for that, there's a serious resource problem you probably won't fix by adding extra layers of cache?

Obviously hard to say without any specs of the system, soft and hardware, but my suggestion would be to see if you can just let them open their connections by increasing the limit, and fiddle with the server variables a bit, instead of monkey-patching your system by using a memcached as an in-between layer.

Comment: The database has been optimized as much as it possibly can. We even hired Percona to squeeze every single bit out of it, but the amount of connections is simply too great. You do have a very valid point about memcache, however as far as I understand, it ejects the oldest data. The stats data would only be there for a few minutes before getting committed to DB.

Comment: I think there are 2 basic options. 1 is memory, 2 is disk. You'd expect bottlenecks with both of them, but in this case database connections seem to be the problem? If disc isn't the problem, you could save your data to disc in a more plain way then a database, and later on import it with a script. That is, if indeed database connections are the only issue, as I/O will not be cheap. Maybe there is an in-between memory based solution possible, but I can't recommend you one :)

Comment: Sounds to me like you may need to invest in some new hardware then... :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with statistic data. But please don't use memcached for it. You can't be sure that ALL your items will moved to DB. You can loose data and/or double process data.

You should analyse your bottleneck against how much data you are writing/reading and how many connections you need. And than switch to something scalable like Hadoop, Cassandra, Scripe and other systems.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to provide additional information on the platform that you are running: O/S, database (version), storage engine, RAM, CPU (if possible)?
2. Are you inserting into a single table or more than one table?
3. Can you disable the indexes on the tables you are inserting into as this slows down the insert functions.
4. Are you running any triggers or stored procedures to compute values as you insert the raw data?

Comment: using latest Ubuntu with mysql 5.1.59. 48GB ram, dual quad CPUs. Most tables are InnoDB. 3 tables need to be inserted into/updated. There is  heavy reads going from 2 of those tables at the same time, so indexes are necessary. No triggers or procedures.

Comment: Are you using innodb_file_per_table? How big is your innodb_buffer_pool_size - do the tables fit in memory? That may speed up performance